# jquery reload div X amount of seconds problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know there are a million examples and tutrials on how to reload a DIV in jquery every X amount of seconds, here is the example code I am using right now

```
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval( 
function(){ 
  $('#notificationcontainer').load('http://localhost/member/beta_new/notifications.inc.php'). 
  fadeIn("slow"); 
}, 10000); 
</script>
```

The above code loads the DIV notificationcontainer

My problem is I need to load DIV notificationcontainer on page load and then refresh every X amount of seconds, this code currently makes the page wait X amount of time on initial page load and I need to show the div right away on page load but then also update it every X amount of time, please help

Comment: Why are you using examplecode? Shouldn't you write your own code? Even the most basic understanding of jQuery would have answered this for you. Read through their documentation, it's great for beginners.

Comment: Basicly I have been researching this for a couple days and every code I have seen shows to do it this way so that's why I am asking for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function which loads the DIV, call it once in document.ready and pass it to setInterval function so that will be called periodically.

```
<script>
    var refreshNotification = 
        function() 
        {   
            $('#notificationcontainer').load('http://localhost/member/beta_new/notifications.inc.php');
            fadeIn("slow"); 
        };

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            refreshNotification();
            var autoRefresh = setInterval(refreshNotification, 10000);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, It returns this error for me,
 
any idea to fix.......


 missing : after property id refreshNotification();

Comment: Oops. There was an error in my code. Check my answer again, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Run the function before calling `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function() out, give it a name, then onload call that function along with a setInterval that calls the same function.